# How to enlarge MPMoviePlayerController controls in a subview

Tags: xcode, ios6, controls, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am adding an MPMoviePlayerController object that streams an .mp3 and displays a subview in the main viewcontroller. See the link for the controls that I get when it starts playing. How can I enlarge this control bar if possible?

[image]